# How to use a Random number Generator in C#?

Tags: c#, random, dice

I created a Windows Forms application using Visual Studio Professional in C#. In my program I prompt the user to input the number of rolls he/she wants and then they press enter to get the numbers.

The numbers are shown in the same form under a label and get tallied up. I know how to tally the numbers know but I can't get the random number generator to generate the number of rolls the user inputs.

This is what i am doing:

```
Random randGen = new Random;
int oneRoll = randGen.Next(1,7) + randGen(1, 7);
```

I want the same program to occur the number of times the user wants. I tried a `for` loop but couldn't get what I wanted.

Comment: What *did* you get with the loop? And what did your loop look like?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i <= numRolls; i++)                                                                                 i = oneroll;

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Random randGen = new Random();
var rolls = new List<int>();
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRolls; i++)
{
    int randomNum1 = randGen.Next(1,7);
    int randomNum2 = randGen.Next(1,7);
    sum += randomNum1 + randomNum2;
    rolls.Add(randomNum1);
    rolls.Add(randomNum2);
}
```

Now all the separate rolls are in rolls, and the sum of them has already been calculated.

**Edited to roll two dice, record them individually, and sum it all together.**

Comment: I have to use two dice so I would use                             randGen.Next(1, 7) + randGen.Next(1, 7);                              so how do I generate what the user inputs for example what if he inputs 1000 for the number of dice roll. How will i make the program repeat for 1000 times

Comment: If you want to keep a record of the different (virtual) die's numbers, you can store them separately, as I've just edited it to do.

Comment: You need to get the user input into int form, in the numberOfRolls variable.  In a Windows Forms application, the easiest way to do this is to have a TextBox for the user to type in, and then when they click a button to roll the dice, you do some code like this to parse it: `int numberOfRolls = int.Parse(myTextBox.Text);`.  Then put the code I have, and it will repeat 1000 times.

Comment: I converted everything that was needed all i need to know is how to roll the same thing for the number of times that is the input.

Answer (score 1):

```
int rolls = Console.ReadLine();
int total = 0; 
Random randGen = new Random(System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
for(int i =0; i<rolls; i++)
{
int oneRoll = randGen.Next(1,7) + randGen.Next(1, 7);
Console.WriteLine("Rolled " + oneRoll);
total += oneRoll;
}

Console.WriteLine("Total " + total);
```

NB. you don't need the Millisecond bit, the seed just makes it more random

Comment: It's a bad idea to recreate a new Random at every iteration.

Comment: I have to use two dice so I would use randGen.Next(1, 7) + randGen.Next(1, 7); so how do I generate what the user inputs for example what if he inputs 1000 for the number of dice roll. How will i make the program repeat for 1000 times

Comment: @Vishal1949 if the user enters 1000 then this code will work, try it. rolls will be 1000 so it will loop through 1000 times, each time generating two numbers between 1 and 6 and adding them to your total.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you create the Random Number generator just once.

Do NOT create it in each loop iteration.

Or, the numbers may not be random because the loop is so tight it will use the same time as the seed in the internal generator.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is totally wrong...

```
Random randGen = new Random(DateTime.Now.Ticks); // unique seed, mostly
int result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < number_of_rolls_the_user_wants; i++)
    result += randGen.Next(2, 14); // (1 - 7) + (1 - 7) = 2 - 14 lol... >.>
```

Replace `number_of_rolls_the_user_wants` with the number of rolls the user wants.
`result` will hold the result.

Also please note that, if you generate many random numbers in a short time, **use the same `Random` object**!

Comment: I have to use two dice so I would use randGen.Next(1, 7) + randGen.Next(1, 7); so how do I generate what the user inputs for example what if he inputs 1000 for the number of dice roll. How will i make the program repeat for 1000 times

Comment: Read what I said after the code... replace that variable with the number of times.

Comment: `randGen.Next(2, 14)` (should end in 13, actually) is *not* the same as `randGen.Next(1, 7) + randGen.Next(1, 7)`.  e.g. 2 is much less likely, when rolling two dice, than 7 is.

Comment: Yes, Mr. Math! So if you add two random numbers between 1 and 7, you get a random number between 2 and 13? What if BOTH ARE 7?

Comment: Look up Random.Next(x, y).  The random number n is x <= n < y, not x <= n <= y.  Also, bet me that if we roll a pair of dice 100 times, 2 will come up as much as 7.  I'll give you a hint: I'll win.

Comment: @Tim S. I finally figured it out... You can't get `7` two times in a row with normal Random... But he wants **dice**, which are real objects and they CAN BOTH ROLL 7. You may have lost contact with reality for a moment. >.>

Comment: It would be a very bad psuedorandom generator, that couldn't produce the same number twice in a row.  My point is that .Next(1, 7) means it produces a number from 1 through 6.  This means that the sum of two of these could be 2 through 12.  It does *not* mean that it's the same as .Next(2, 13).  Also, most dice have 6 sides, so they can't "both" roll 7.  Together, they sum to 7, individually they are  somewhere from 1 to 6.  3 is a more likely sum of two dice than 2 since it can be made of 1+2 or 2+1, where 2 can only be 1+1.  It seems to me that you are the one that lost contact with reality.